# To order alphanumeric values by the number part

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with one column with the following values.

```
|TestId|
--------
| F1   |
| F2   |
| F3   |
| A62  |
| F9   |
| DP45 |
| CAP78|
| F89  |
| F34  |
| F43  |
```

I need to order them based on their numeric parts. So basically I need to get

F1,F2,F3,F9,F34,F43,DP45,A62,CAP78,F89

I tried the below query but got the wrong results.

```
SELECT [TestId] FROM TestingOrder 
ORDER BY LEN(TestId),TestId
```

I get F1,F2,F3,F9,A62,F34,F43,F89,DP45,CAP78 which is not what I want.

How do I fix it to get the order needed?

EDIT : The answer provided works if there are no repeated values. However fails when there are repeated values

For example :

```
|TestId|
--------
| F1   |
| F2   |
| F3   |
| A62  |
| F9   |
| DP45 |
| CAP78|
| F89  |
| F34  |
| F43  |
| F1   |
| F3   |
| F89  |
| F34  |
```

I modified the answer to this

```
select TestId FROM  
(SELECT DISTINCT TestId From TestingOrder) A
cross apply
( values ( convert(int,(substring(TestId, patindex('%[0-9]%', TestId), len(TestId))))) )tt(nos)  
order by nos;
```

The result changes to F1,F2,F3,F34,F43,DP45,A62,CAP78,F89,F9

Comment: Alphanumerical values have very different ordering to numbers. With numbers, the statement `9 < 10` is true, but with a string the statement `'9' < '10'` is false. If ordering is really important (and you don't want a heavy overhead like `PATINDEX` might be), then consider making your ID column a fixed width, with leading 0's in the numerical part (if the alpha part width is fixed), or splitting the ID into 2 columns (the Alpha and Numerical), with a persisted computed column for the full value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use use `patindex()` :

```
select distinct t.*
from TestingOrder t cross apply
     ( values ( convert(int, substring(TestId, patindex('%[0-9]%', TestId), len(TestId)))) 
     ) tt(nos)
order by tt.nos;
```

Comment: This helps. But what if there are multiple values for ex. 2 values of F1 and I will have to group by and then cross apply? I do not want it to appear multiple times

Comment: @TheFallenOne Use 'distinct'

Comment: @GenWan See my latest Edit.